# Loading txt file data into a numpy array / getting an error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text

I'm trying to load a txt file data into a numpy array. It's throwing the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6,50,36'
```

The txt file I am trying to upload into the array is this (this is the full file):

```
6,50,36
2,0,1,3,0,1
1,2,1,2,1,2
2,1,2,1,0,1
0,2,0,2,2,3
0,3,3,3,1,4
2,3,2,3,1,3
```

I've did some research and thought that the "np.loadtxt()" would be an easy solution to load this txt into an array, so this is what I've tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt

f = open('DataNumbers.txt','r')
data_array = float(np.loadtxt(f))  # I thought using 'float' would work for this issue
```

I'm wondering if  the reason this isn't working is because the file contains two blank spaces after 36 on the first line of the txt file?

How can I get this data from the txt file loaded into an array and get rid of this error?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Review docs for `loadtxt` (or `genfromtxt`).  Pay attention to `delimiter`, `usecols`, `dtype`, and `skipheader` (or what ever its called).  The shorted initial line will cause problems.  You may want to skip it.  Remember, the result should be a 2d array with a consistent number of columns.

Comment: `loadtxt` as you use it returns one string per line.  `float` only works with one string representing one number.  You can read the file line by line yourself, but then you have to split it on the delimiter, convert resulting list of strings into a list of numbers, and join those.  That's not hard.

Comment: first row has 3 columns while the rest has 6 columns! would you like to skip first row??!!

Comment: Yes @KhalilAlHooti , its not my original file

Answer (score 1):

```
In [498]: f = open('stack53641413.txt','r')
In [501]: alist = [[int(x) for x in line.split(',')] for line in f]
In [502]: alist
Out[502]: 
[[6, 50, 36],
 [2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1],
 [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3],
 [0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4],
 [2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3]]
In [504]: np.array(alist[1:])
Out[504]: 
array([[2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3],
       [0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3]])
```

What you do with `alist[0]` is your business.

`loadtxt` skipping the difficult first line:

```
In [507]: np.loadtxt(f, dtype='int', delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
Out[507]: 
array([[2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3],
       [0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3]])
```